# one line if statement, ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I am getting this error when I try to add a column to my pandas dataset based on the following conditions.

```
df['name'] = (1 if (df['name2'] > 0) and (df['name3'] == 0) else 0)
```

I would really appreciate some help with this, I am very new to python.

Thanks.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o) solve your question?

Comment: What happened when you tried what you were told?

Comment: When I use the '&' sign I still get the same error

Comment: @anona Yes because you then run into a similar problem with `if`

Comment: @superbrain It's mentioned in the accepted answer in the question that Jan linked.

Comment: Anyway, the point is that both the `and` and the `if` will try to assign truth values to an entire array, and that you need to use equivalents that will do element-by-element operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.where`:

```
df['name'] = np.where((df['name2'] > 0) & (df['name3'] == 0), 1, 0)
```

Comment: But you are still using `and`. You need `&`.

Comment: This gave the same error, then I changed the 'and' to '&' and it worked, thanks

Comment: Ok cool, you can mark this as the answer if it worked.